HTML issues with variables
Hello I am just learning python, I am just about through my first semester. I am running into a problem with adding variables into your HTML code. To be clear we have not covered this particular area in class, so I haven't been successful in finding the answers in my book. I think I have everything correct except I don't know how to add my variables into my HTML code. I just need to incorporate the "name" variable and the "describe" variable into my code.
#This program is designed to take input from the user and generate a web page
name= input('Enter your name:')
describe= input('Describe yourself:')

function= open('index.html','w')
function.write("<html>\n<head>\n<title>\n Output Data in an HTML file\
            </title>\n</head> <body><h1>{name}</h1>\n </center>\n<hr/>\
            {describe}\n<hr/>\n </body>\n</html>")
function.close()


Formatted String Literals

Simplest fix... Put an f character just before the HTML string literal.

see also: How do I create a multiline Python string with inline variables?

name = input('Enter your name: ')
describe = input('Describe yourself: ')

# Open the file in write mode
with open('index.html', 'w') as function:
    # Use an f-string to insert variables into the HTML
    function.write(f"""<html>
<head>
    <title>Output Data in an HTML file</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{name}</h1>
    <hr/>
    <p>{describe}</p>
    <hr/>
</body>
</html>
""")

